# Apache with mod_wsgi and python returns 500 periodically

Tags: python, apache2, flask, wsgi

I have a website running on Python and Flask. 4 times out of 10 it returns a 500 error, randomly as far as I can tell.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello world!"
```

Here's my .wsgi file (I'm using virtualenv, and activating it before importing the application):

```
activate_this = '/path/to/app/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from myapp import app as application
```

This is my Apache host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=ubuntu group=ubuntu processes=2 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/app/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any pointers to debug this are welcome!

**EDIT:**

Apache error.log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=29581): Target WSGI script '/path/to/app/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=29581): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/path/to/app/myapp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/app/myapp.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
    from myapp import app as application
ImportError: No module named myapp
```

It seems that one of the two processes (29581) is not running the virtualenv bit, and therefore not locating the files to import.

**EDIT 2:**

It's the local file myapp.py that is not being found in the PATH. I needed to include this at the top of my .wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/myapp')

activate_this = '/path/to/myapp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

from myapp import app as application
```

Comment: Look at the log files.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add the local path the the PATH variable in the wsgi file